# Magento 1.7 server overload

Tags: magento-1.7

My website ( www.librariamaranatha.ro ) is overloading server. It is working for 5 minutes then it is down for another 5 minutes and so on... The admin page is blank.

I have installed SUPEE 1533, SUPEE 5344, SUPEE 5994 but the problem is not fixed.

Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Thank you!

Comment: It might be wrong server configuration. Hard to tell with your given info.

Comment: http://librariaumanitara.ro/magento-check.php     "Congratulations! Your server meets the requirements for Magento"

Comment: The server is overloaded when I try to access admin. In client area the website is working fine.